# Scraping Beautiful Soup - find a value from a table

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

After I scrape team names or date (not in table), I try to extract some odds from a table.

https://prnt.sc/Vcz_GNAz77ni
url: https://www.oddsmath.com/football/england/premier-league-1281/2022-08-28/wolverhampton-wanderers-vs-newcastle-united-3882295/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.oddsmath.com/football/england/premier-league-1281/2022-08-28/wolverhampton-wanderers-vs-newcastle-united-3882295/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

match = soup.find('li', {'class':'active'}).text
print(match)

date = soup.find('time', {'class':'event-time'})['datetime']
print(date)

All_1X2_FT = soup.find_all('table', id = 'table-odds-cat-0')
print(All_1X2_FT)
```

Output:

```
Wolverhampton Wanderers vs Newcastle United
2022-08-28T15:00:00+02:00
[<table class="tbl-list-odds" id="table-odds-cat-0">
<thead></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>]
```

But from here cannot find any way to proceed to a particular bookmaker (differentiated by 'data-x-id') or for a specific outcome (class = 'odds odds -1' for this example)

I appreciate any help on it, Thank you.

Comment: First and foremost: https://xkcd.com/2116/ Second, if you really want to be helped, post a minimal reproducible example, and also confirm the url.

Comment: Thanks @platipus_on_fire, I edited the post, I hope is more clear now.

Comment: Does that website require a login in order to display the table?

Comment: No, you can see the odds or table without login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is being hydrated in page from an API, after the page html is loaded, so you need to scrape that API endpoint for that particular table' data. This is one way of obtaining it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/live-odds.json/?event_id=3882295&cat_id=0&include_exchanges=1&language=en&country_code=JP'
r = requests.get(url)
json_obj = r.json()['data']
the_list = []
for k in json_obj:
    try:
        the_list.append((k, json_obj[k]['x-id'], json_obj[k]['live']['updated'], json_obj[k]['live']['1'], json_obj[k]['live']['X'], json_obj[k]['live']['2']))
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(k, 'error')
df = pd.DataFrame(list(set(the_list)), columns = ['Betting Platform', 'X-ID', 'Updated at', '1', 'X', '2'])
print(df)
```

This would return:

```
Betfair error
Betting Platform    X-ID    Updated at  1   X   2
0   Campobet    64  2022-08-17 16:39:17 2.670   3.200   2.670
1   Bettogoal   83  2022-08-18 14:01:44 2.740   3.450   2.630
2   Suprabets   80  2022-08-18 14:07:53 2.800   3.530   2.690
3   10Bet   12  2022-08-18 12:45:17 2.750   3.300   2.650
4   Betway  16  2022-08-18 09:47:14 2.700   3.200   2.700
5   Winner  81  2022-08-17 16:02:29 2.750   3.750   2.500
6   Dafabet 13  2022-08-18 17:38:08 2.520   3.150   2.740
7   Titanbet    11  2022-08-17 16:03:53 2.650   3.200   2.700
8   Rabona  65  2022-08-17 16:39:17 2.670   3.200   2.670
9   Megapari    74  2022-08-16 19:27:11 2.835   3.500   2.642
10  Librabet    66  2022-08-17 16:39:24 2.670   3.200   2.670
11  BetClic 5   2022-08-17 16:03:15 2.700   3.300   2.730
12  Marathonbet 38  2022-08-16 19:29:25 2.780   3.450   2.590
13  bet-at-home 4   2022-08-17 16:02:35 2.650   3.200   2.650
14  DoubleBet   40  2022-08-16 19:27:12 2.835   3.500   2.642
15  FEZbet  84  2022-08-17 17:49:45 2.670   3.200   2.670
16  Tipico  56  2022-08-15 11:44:40 2.700   3.200   2.650
17  BetWinner   41  2022-08-16 19:33:07 2.835   3.500   2.642
18  Unibet  2   2022-08-15 06:50:45 2.800   3.400   2.500
19  1XBET   32  2022-08-16 19:27:12 2.835   3.500   2.642
20  888sport    35  2022-08-15 06:55:40 2.800   3.400   2.500
21  SBOBET  8   2022-08-18 10:52:16 2.651   3.016   2.555
```

You can further dissect and analyze that json response, to get some other info as well.

Comment: Thank you! I will investigate more on how to analyze the json response. Is there any way I can extract the jsons in a list from a page like https://www.oddsmath.com/#dropping-odds-tab? So for each match to have that json. (previously I extract the urls of these matches/page with selenium). It is my first scraping project and I cannot find the place to extract these jsons, apart of your example and observing that the event ID can be editable - unique for each match

Comment: What you could do is inspect the Dev Tools - Network tab for that page, when you select a betting platfom. For example, when you select 1XBET from that dropdown, the following API is being accessed: https://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/dropping-odds.json/?sport_type=soccer&provider_id=32&cat_id=0&interval=60&sortBy=1&limit=30&language=en You can then scrape that API (which apprarently refreshes every 60 seconds or so).

Comment: If that is easy to check @platipus_on_fire, when I try to inspect an API after I login, I have a new format of url, including auth 'https://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/live-odds.json/?auth_ctx=premium-user&event_id=3880115&cat_id=0&include_exchanges=1&language=en&country_code=RO&hidden_providers=7,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,15,16,18,20,22,30,31,34,35,36,38,40,41,51,54,56,60,64,65,66,67,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,83,84' .Copying the link to Chrome it shows me the json file, but when read it through python I receive the 403 response. Do I need to include any credentials into the requests?

Comment: You can try adding a header with a valid user-agent to get request , if you think they might block scraping. Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ @Psychomantis